# check50 not working properly

Tags: greedy, cs50

check50 gives weird output please help

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    int amount,n25,n10,n5,n1,total;
    int rem;
    float gamount;
    printf("O hai!");
do{
    printf("How much change is owed?\n");
    gamount = GetFloat();
}while(gamount<0);
    amount = (int) round(gamount *100.00);
    rem = round(amount);
    n25 =(int) rem /25;
    rem = rem %25;
    n10 = rem /10;
    rem = rem%10;
    n5 = rem /5;
    rem = rem%5;    
    n1 = rem /1;
    rem = rem%1;
    total = n25+n10+n5+n1;
    printf("%d",total);
    return 0;
}
```

check50 output:

```
*~/workspace/pset1/ $ check50 2015.fall.pset1.greedy greedy.c
:) greedy.c exists
:) greedy.c compiles
:( input of 0.41 yields output of 4
   \ expected output, but not "4"
:( input of 0.01 yields output of 1
   \ expected output, but not "1"
:( input of 0.15 yields output of 2
   \ expected output, but not "2"
:( input of 1.6 yields output of 7
   \ expected output, but not "7"
:( input of 23 yields output of 92
   \ expected output, but not "92"
:( input of 4.2 yields output of 18
   \ expected output, but not "18"
:) rejects a negative input like -.1
:) rejects a non-numeric input of "foo"
:) rejects a non-numeric input of ""
https://sandbox.cs50.net/checks/f9c8501c99a848df82d8bd0df231a6ea
```

i tried changing the printf("%d",total) statement to printf(total) but it results in compile error
compiling using 
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow    greedy.c  -lcs50 -lm -o greedy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:
    `printf("%d",total);`
try using this:
    `printf("%d\n",total);`